# Relax password complexity requirements as password length increases

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have the following JavaScript function:

```
function checkPassword(password) {
    if (password.match(/[A-Z]/) 
      && password.match(/[a-z]/) 
      && password.match(/[0-9]/) 
      && password.match(/[£:#@~\.,|(etc....)]/) 
      && password.length >= 6) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }  
}
```

What I'd like to do is change it so that when password length is over 16, only require 3 of upper case, lower case, numbers and symbols and over 32 characters long only require 2 of the character types. How would I go about this?

This is what I have so far but it seems huge and I'm sure there must be a better, more efficient or at least tidier way:

```
function checkPassword(password) {
    var matched = 0;
    if (password.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        matched++;
    }
    if (password.match(/[a-z]/)) {
        matched++;
    }
    if (password.match(/[0-9]/)) { 
        matched++;
    }
    if (password.match(/[£:#@~\.,|(etc....)]/)) { 
        matched++;
    }
    if (matched >= 4 && password.length >= 6) {
        return true;
    }
    if (matched >= 3 && password.length >= 16) {
        return true;
    }
    if (matched >= 2 && password.length >= 32) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think my problem is the fact that I have two variables `matched` and `password.length` that I need to check values of.

Comment: Seems like you would need an if else of some sort...

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of character type categories it matches and add that to `Math.floor(password.length/16.0)` (i.e., the number of whole times 16 goes into the password). Then, just check if that total value is at least 4. This still requires the first part of your code:

```
function checkPassword(password) {
    var matched = 0;
    if (password.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        matched++;
    }
    if (password.match(/[a-z]/)) {
        matched++;
    }
    if (password.match(/[0-9]/)) { 
        matched++;
    }
    if (password.match(/[£:#@~\.,|(etc....)]/)) { 
        matched++;
    }
```

...But the rest is simpler, leaving you with just one condition to check:

```
    matched += Math.floor(password.length/16.0);
    if (matched >= 4 && password.length > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you wanted to shorten it even more, you could put your regexes in a list and loop over them.

Bear in mind that this will make it hard for you to explain to users what's missing if their password isn't good enough: generally it's helpful to display an error message specific to what the user's password is missing (e.g. an uppercase letter, a symbol, etc). You won't have this, because you won't know what they're missing (and they have multiple options to fix it, so there isn't really a particular thing they're missing). If you want to display good, specific error messages, you're stuck with long code.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to give additional thoughts to this but how about a trick like this:

```
var password = "S0m3p@ssword";
var count= 0;

var r = password.replace(/([A-Z])|([a-z])|([0-9])|([£:#@~\.,])/g,function(match,upperChars,lowersChars,numbers,specialChars){
    count = count +1;

    if (count >= 4 && password.length >= 6) {
        return "match1";
    }
    if (count >= 3 && password.length >= 16) {
        return "match2";
    }
    if (count >= 2 && password.length >= 32) {
        return "match3";
    }
    return "";
});

console.log(r);
```

In the above example if `r.length > 0` it means password is valid.